# Why does this Javascript work in Firefox, but not Internet Explorer?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, firefox

```
  <img src="images/butAdd.png" onclick="addField(1,1);" />

  <div id="divField"></div>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    function addField(count, type) {
        var bid = document.getElementById("bid").value;
        $("#divField").append("<a href='#' onClick='javascript:removeField(\"#bow" + bid + "\"); return false;'><img src='images/closeSmall.png' /></a>");  
        }

    function removeField(bid) {
        $(bid).remove();
    }
 </script>
```

Consider this Javascript code that works fine in Firefox, but not in Internet Explorer.

The function `addField()` works, but `removeField()` does not.

Any ideas on why this wouldn't work, or any workarounds?

Comment: The functionality appears to be,
1. Get the input value from #bid and construct an anchor that calls the removeField function passing in the selector #bow+bidvalue.
2. Clicking the link removes the element, #bow+bidvalue

Where bidvalue is the value of the #bid element's input.  Am I missing anything?

Comment: Looking at the code here, there is no element with ID 'bid' when addField() is called, therefore that function will fail.

Comment: Whatever you're doing, your doing it the hard way! Go learn more jQuery it'll help you to simplify your code.

Answer (score 3):

Try this one.

```
function addField(count, type) {
                            $("#divField").append("<a href='#' onClick='javascript:removeField(); return false;'><img src='images/closeSmall.png' /></a>");      
                    }

                    function removeField() {
                            $("#bid").remove();
                    }
```

Answer (score 3):

onclick event should not have 'javascript:' in front of code. Such string should be only when you use 'href=' to put JS code.

Answer (score 2):

I think it is do with the variable called 'bid'. The value for the variable is assigned only when you are calling the addField() and it is local to that method.

In removeField() the value for 'bid' is undefined, that is why it is not working.

Try changing the removeField() like this

```
function removeField() {
    var bid = document.getElementById("bid").value;
    $(bid).remove();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your addFiled can look like:

```
$("<a href='#'><img src='images/closeSmall.png' /></a>").appendTo("#divField")
  .click(function() {
    $("#bid").remove();
  })
```

Answer (score 0):

try changing:

```
var bid = document.getElementById("bid").value;
```

to

```
var bid = $("#bid").val();
```

I think there is a quirk in the way IE does the .value vs firefox